# I can't push a docker file in Amazon sage maker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dockerfile, amazon-sagemaker, yolov5

[image][image: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF0YN.png)]
I'm trying to deploy yolov5 algorithm de AWS sagemaker, some people suggested me to follow https://github.com/RamVegiraju/SageMaker-Deployment/tree/master/RealTime/BYOC/PreTrained-Examples/SpacyNER but when I try to execute the first cell I'm getting the error shown in these pictures, can someone please tell me how to fix this problem ?

I tried to change the dockerfile, but I got the same errors.

```
Command 'b'\n# Name of algo -> ECR\nalgorithm_name=sm-pretrained-spacy\n\ncd container\n\n#make serve executable\nchmod +x NER/serve\n\naccount=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)\n\n# Region, defaults to us-west-2\nregion=$(aws configure get region)\nregion=${region:-us-east-1}\n\nfullname="${account}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${algorithm_name}:latest"\n\n# If the repository doesn\'t exist in ECR, create it.\naws ecr describe-repositories --repository-names "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null 2>&1\n\nif [ $? -ne 0 ]\nthen\n    aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${algorithm_name}" > /dev/null\nfi\n\n# Get the login command from ECR and execute it directly\naws ecr get-login-password --region ${region}|docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${fullname}\n\n# Build the docker image locally with the image name and then push it to ECR\n# with the full name.\n\ndocker build  -t ${algorithm_name} .\ndocker tag ${algorithm_name} ${fullname}\n\ndocker push ${fullname}\n'' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: a guide for *good* question asking:   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Is your work directory also labelled as NER? Make sure you have the proper region as that cell and Docker configured.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is was due to permissions, I have not accorded the permission to my IAM user